# Using built-in data in an R package

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to use built-in data in an R package (this package [here](https://github.com/alishinski/clustRcompaR).

I've used the `usethis::use_data_raw()` and `usethis::use_data()` (formerly from the devtools package) to set up a directory (and script) to process the raw data and the directory with the raw data itself (see `data-raw` and `data` [here](https://github.com/alishinski/clustRcompaR).

However, when I load the package and then type the name of the data - `inaugural_addresses` - it does not load. However, when I load the package and run `data("inaugural_addresses")`, it loads the `data.frame` into the environment, e.g.:

```
> inaugural_addresses
Error: object 'inaugural_addresses' not found
> data("inaugural_addresses")
# this loads the data.frame into the environment
```

It seems like I must be not documenting something correctly - but I can't find out what. How can I load the built-in data without the use of the `data()` function?